# How do I remove dot and number in just one column?

Tags: awk, sed

I have data like this:

```
head l4
chr   pos a1 a2 a3 variant_id         pval_nominal gene_id
chr1 13550 G A b38 chr1_13550_G_A_b38 0.375614 ENSG00000227232.5
chr1 14671 G C b38 chr1_14671_G_C_b38 0.474708 ENSG00000227232.5
chr1 14677 G A b38 chr1_14677_G_A_b38 0.699887 ENSG00000227232.5
```

I would like to remove in the last column dot and number afterwards, which is not always 5, it can be any number

so that I have data like this:

```
chr pos a1 a2 a3 variant_id pval_nominal gene_id
chr1 13550 G A b38 chr1_13550_G_A_b38 0.375614 ENSG00000227232
chr1 14671 G C b38 chr1_14671_G_C_b38 0.474708 ENSG00000227232
chr1 14677 G A b38 chr1_14677_G_A_b38 0.699887 ENSG00000227232
```

I tried this:

```
sed 's/\..*$//' l4 > l4_clean
```

but this removes many other things.

Comment: Because you have `.*` it willmatch *any* character including the final dot. So your sed find a dot (the first) and then all the characters afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want to modify the last field, so use a tool that can work with fields, like `awk`. In `awk`, the variable `$NF` is the last field, so you can do:

```
awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$NF)}1' l4 > l4_clean
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @anamaria you're welcome! By the way, you might be interested in our sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 4):

Just apply a more specific regex pattern (to match numbers/digits):

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//' l4 > l4_clean
```

Comment: That will also delete a dot if it's the last character on a line, but I doubt that will be a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command if last character can be digit or alphabet or any symbol after dot (`.`).

```
sed "s/\..$//g" filename

awk '{gsub(/\..*/,"",$NF);print $0}' filename
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'\..')
m=open('i.txt','r')
for i in m:
    p=re.sub(k,"",i)
    print p,
```